# Is possible to have multiple triggers for the same table?

Tags: mysql

I'm learning about databases (MySQL on wampserver)

I have a trigger and I want to run this code on it but the compiler tells me I have a syntax error. (After insert on parent table)

```
INSERT INTO test_a (a1, a2)
Values(New.Value1, New.Value2)

INSERT INTO test_b (a1, a2)
Values(New.Value1, New.Value2)

INSERT INTO test_c (a1, a2)
Values(New.Value1, New.Value2)
```

The problem comes when I try to compile this, I get an error on syntax. It works only with one sentence. In localhost I can use multiple triggers with the same event. But on the school test page I can't do that, I get the message "This version of maria db doesnt yet support multiple triggers with the same event" when I try to do it.

What can I do ?

Comment: Please read [mcve]. It would be helpful if you can post the trigger code.

Comment: Aren't you missing semicolons after each statement?

Comment: Thats all the code I'm using phpmyadmin UI.  I want to insert A row in 2 tables after insert in the parent table because I cant create 2 triggers for each table, I want to use 1 trigger  but I'm unable to reach that.

INSERT INTO Test (a1, a2, ID_Parent)
VALUES (new.value1, New.value2, New.ID);

INSERT INTO Test2 (a1, a2, ID_Banca )
VALUES (new.Value1, New.Value2, New.ID);

Comment: There has to be more code. What about `CREATE TRIGGER....`